# The d3 js initialization failed in firefox with locker service activated (Summer 17)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, d3, firefox

The issue is that I am trying to draw a tree using the d3 js library and it works perfectly in chrome and edge, but when I tried to use firefox for this purpose the tree didn't look correctly. The mistakes were not found in console and only when I set breakpoint in d3 js library (v4.10.0) in parseSvg function the next error was found:

```
Exception: TypeError

columnNumber: 9

fileName: https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ChXnmCA7O-Fvbs9jcqI9Ow/aura_proddebug.js

lineNumber: 20848

message: cannot use the given object as a weak map key

stack: "ls_setKey@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ChXnmCA7O-Fvbs9jcqI9Ow/aura_proddebug.js:20848:9LockerService/SecureObject.$filterEverything$@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ChXnmCA7O-Fvbs9jcqI9Ow/aura_proddebug.js:21110:33LockerService/SecureObject.$createFilteredPropertyStateless$/descriptor.get@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ChXnmCA7O-Fvbs9jcqI9Ow/aura_proddebug.js:21367:16get@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ChXnmCA7O-Fvbs9jcqI9Ow/aura_proddebug.js:19958:18parseSvg@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:2786:7interpolateTransform/<@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:2835:9attrFunction$1/<@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3449:26tween@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3488:26start@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3256:15schedule@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3197:32timerFlush@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3062:40wake@/resource/1500540200000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3072:5SecureFunction@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/ChXnmCA7O-Fvbs9jcqI9Ow/aura_proddebug.js:21018:31"
```

What do u recommend me to fix this issue? 
[image]

Updated 08/04/2017

It looks like the org has been updated and the following error is shown in a pop up now:

```
[cannot use the given object as a weak map key] ls_setKey()@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_proddebug.js:20854:9    

LockerService/SecureObject.$filterEverything$()@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_proddebug.js:21116:33
LockerService/SecureObject.$createFilteredPropertyStateless$/descriptor.get()@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_proddebug.js:21373:16
get()@https://hierarchytreevrpdev-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/mCBwk69pLuvM0O_Xv2hHog/aura_proddebug.js:19961:18
defaultExtent$1()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:16121:5
Gesture()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:16292:19
gesture()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:16284:12
schedule/<()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:16258:40
call()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:793:61
start()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3249:5
schedule()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3197:32
timerFlush()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3062:40
wake()@/resource/1500643238000/sftree__Resources/vendors/d3/d3.v4.10.0.js:3072:5
```

In adition, before locker service was enforced everything had worked in firefox.

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same problem in firefox.

Comment: Any update on this issue please? I'm having similar one.